# How to examine whether a complex function of the polar form is differentiable or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example, suppose that I have $f(re^{i\theta}) = r + i\theta\  r>0, -\pi < \theta < \pi$, I want to calculate $f'(z)$.

Thought: For the regular situation we have the inverse of CR equation to help us examine wether a function is differentiable or not(partially, since it is only a sufficient condition)

But under the circumstance of the polar form how should I proceed? For the example discussed above, the definition gives me that I should check whether $lim_{(r,\theta) \to (r_0,\theta_0)}\frac{r+i\theta - r_0 -i\theta_0}{re^{i\theta}-r_0e^{i\theta_0}}$ exists. Then how should I proceed from here, any hint?

Edit: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/teaching/classes/425/crpolar.pdf
This document here solves CR equation of the polar form. But my question concerns that if I know those CR equations are satisfied, can I deduce that $f(z)$ is holomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

A document that might interest you.
http://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/teaching/classes/425/crpolar.pdf

Comment: But my problems here involve the inverse of Cauchy Riemann equation, the document already assumes that $f(z)$ is holomorphic

Comment: The cartesian Cauchy-Riemann equations are necessary and sufficient conditions for the function to be holomorphic. I do agree that in this document, they don't present the polar one to be a sufficient condition. But the two equation presented can simply be viewed as a coordinate transformation of the cartesian equations from (x,y) to (r,theta), which is invertible. Thus I believe the polar and the cartesian equations are equivalent and so are both a necessary and sufficient condition for holomorphy.

Answer (score 0):

See [Cauchy-Riemann Equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html) for the answer to your question.

Comment: To use Cauchy Riemann first you have to show that it is holomorhic right？

Comment: From [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations): "In the field of complex analysis in mathematics, the Cauchy–Riemann equations, named after Augustin Cauchy and Bernhard Riemann, consist of a system of two partial differential equations which, together with certain continuity and differentiability criteria, form a necessary and sufficient condition for a complex function to be complex differentiable, that is, holomorphic."

Comment: Yes, but what is the situation for polar forms? If $f$ is differentiable then it is  not hard to derive the CR equation for the polar form, but if I want to prove the other direction is also true, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Your $f(z)=|z|+i$arg$(z)$. Is $|z|$ differentiable at $z=0$? Is arg($z$) defined at $z=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Express $f$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, i.e., consider the pullback
$$g(x,y):=r(x,y)+i\theta(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+i\arctan{y\over x}\qquad(x>0)\ ,$$
and check whether this $g$ satisfies the CR-equations. Similar expressions are valid for $y<0$ and $y>0$, and lead to the same conclusion.

Comment: But arctan can only take values in $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ here